# instead of encoding, i am trying that strings convert to integer but where is the problem?

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
data["column"] = [2 if x=="xxx", 1 if x=="yyy" else 0 for x in data["column"]]

--> data["drive"] = [2 if x=="fwd", 1 if x=="4wd" else 0 for x in data["drive"]]
                                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: `2 if x=="xxx", 1 if x=="yyy" else 0` is an incorrect syntax because there sould be and `else` instead of your comma like so `2 if x=="xxx" else 1 if x=="yyy" else 0`. You sould  read [this](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/) about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.get` + list comprehension:

```py
x = ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "xxx", "zzz", "yyy"]
m = {"xxx": 2, "yyy": 1}
y = [m.get(i, 0) for i in x]
assert y == [2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`2 if x=="fwd"` requires an else statement.

If `x!="fwd"`, then your list wouldn't know what element should be there

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

```
temp_array = []

for x in data['column']:
    value = 0
    if x == 'xxx': value = 2
    if x == 'yyy': value = 1
    temp_array.append(value)

data['column'] = temp_array

temp_array = []

for x in data['drive']:
    value = 0
    if x == 'fwd': value = 2
    if x == '4wd': value = 1
    temp_array.append(value)

data['drive'] = temp_array
```